# Check text for multiple substrings

Tags: r

I am trying to do some text mining, and part of it is to get texts that contain certain names. So I need to check a text for multiple substrings. But using grepl with a column as pattern returns the following error:

```
In grepl(comp$n, text$text) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Which makes sense since `"MIKE"` is the first element. Of the pattern. Am I using grepl wrong, can pattern only be a single element and do I need to approach this differently?

[image]

I'd like it to return TRUE for all of them in column text_c

Below is my code:

```
comp <- as.data.frame(c("MIKE", "ALPHA", "DELTA"))
names(comp) = "n"

text <- as.data.frame(c("@DELTA Falkenrath", "@DELTA, @ALPHA hello world", "@MIKE yoyo"))
names(text) = "text"

text$text_c = grepl(comp$n, text$text)
```

Comment: The first argument of grep (`pattern=`), must be a character vector of length 1. The warning tells you that the function will only take the first element of `comp$n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it said in the warning message, `grepl` will only use one pattern to match. However, you can make a pattern to cover all of your names by joining them with an OR "|".

```
PAT = paste(comp$n, collapse="|")
grepl(PAT, text$text)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: ahh smart! Thanks alot :)